# How can I find all of the permutations consisting of 1 element from a variable number of arrays of variable length?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I have an array `U` of arrays `D` that vary in length. I need to be able to return all permutations of array indices that would select a different permutation consisting of 1 element from each set. I also require that this alorithm gets represented as an object that only remembers the last permutation, and returns the next permutation with a get_next method.

For instance, `U = [array_of_size_n1, array_of_size_n2, array_of_size_n3]` There would be `n1*n2*n3` permutations, each **3** elements long.

**Edit:** the number of sets also varies.

Comment: You are using the wrong terminology.  The correct term for what you are asking for is Cartesian Product.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: @James - "the number of sets also varys in length" does not make sense.  The "number of sets" is a number.  It does not have a length.

Comment: Thank you sir. I thought a term for this probably existed, but kinda hard to search for it if all you have to go on is the phenomenon that it describes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using python, this is part of the standard library: `itertools.product`. But assuming you're not, here's a pseudocode version.

```
// Create an initialised array of indexes.
int[] index0(arrays) {
    // We require all arrays to be non-empty.
    for a in arrays {
        assert len(a) != 0;
    }
    return new int[len(arrays)];
}

// Increment the indices. Returns false when the indices wrap round to the start.
bool next_index(indices, arrays) {
    for (i = len(indices) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        indices[i] += 1
        if indices[i] < len(arrays[i]) {
            return true;
        }
        indices[i] = 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use it like this (assuming none of your arrays are empty). This example prints out every combination of elements from the arrays.

```
indices = index0(arrays); 
{
    for (i = 0; i < len(arrays); ++i) {
        print arrays[i][indices[i]];
    }
    print
} while next_index(indices);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep a counter for your individual position in each array. In your get_next method increase the counter for one and mod it by the length of the array. Then you just increase the next counter every time the previous one rolls over to 0;

```
if (pos3 == array_of_size_n3 -1)
{
   if (pos2 == size_of_array_2 -1)
   {
       pos1 = (pos1 + 1) % size_of_array_1

   }
   pos2 = (pos2 + 1) % size_of_array_2
}
pos3 = (pos3 + 1) % size_of_array_3

print array1[pos1], array2[pos2], array3[pos3]
```

EDIT: In the case the number of arrays varies, hold your position variables in an array. Actually that would probably be better anyway. That way you can refer to the pos variable in the same way you refer to the array itself.

Comment: nice and concise! I rank it better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

So ... what about this *isn't* straightforward?

You want an iterator. You want it to iterate over the last array. When it gets to the end of that array, increment its current position in the second-last array and go back to the start of the last array.

psuedocode using C#s `yield return` syntax:

```
foreach n1 in a1
    foreach n2 in a2
        foreach n3 in a3
            yield return (n1, n2, n3)
```

EDIT: If the number of sets varies, you could use some form of recursion:

```
function next(list)
    firstArray = list.first
    iterator = iterator(list.rest)
    if !iterator
        foreach i in firstArray
            yield return i
    else
        foreach i in firstArray
            while (iterator.hasNext)
                yield return (i, iterator.next)
```

Consider the behaviour when a list of length 1 is passed in, then consider the behaviour for a list of length 2, and satisfy yourself that it does in fact work.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that there are a variable number of sets

Comment: @James somewhere along the line, you're going to have to do a little legwork for yourself. Although Anon didn't address the fact that there are variable number of sets, this is something you should be able to figure out on your own since others are giving the rest to you.

Comment: Though to be fair, implementing a variable number of sets based on a solution with nested loops is often nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

To tack on to what Anon said, you don't just loop over them. You maintain state in your class so that you know what your last index was for each array. The logic is the same, but you don't run in a continuous loop. The pseudo-code logic would be:

```
get_next()
{
  oldn3 = this.n3;
  oldn2 = this.n2;
  oldn1 = this.n1;

  if(this.n3 == this.a3.Count)
     this.n3 = 0;
  else
     this.n3++;

  if(oldn3 > this.n3)
    if(this.n2 == this.a2.Count)
      this.n2 = 0;
    else
      this.n2++;

  if(oldn2 > this.n2)
    if(this.n1 == this.a1.Count)
      this.n1 = 0;
    else
      this.n1++;

  if(oldn1 > this.n1)
    return NO_MORE_PERMS;

  return [n1,n2,n3];  
}

getCurrent()
{
  return [n1,n2,n3];
}
```

Comment: to make this work for arrays of arbitrary length, store your n1, n2, n3, etc in an array. This array is indexed such that index i is the current element for the set i; Also, be mindful of your bounds-checking. on a 0-based system, what i have above would not work.