# Efficient method to find permutations of variable number of arrays containing varibale number of elements

Tags: java, c, algorithm, permutation, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find all of the permutations consisting of 1 element from a variable number of arrays of variable length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189303/how-can-i-find-all-of-the-permutations-consisting-of-1-element-from-a-variable-n)

Suppose I have n arrays with elements like below

```
 a1 -> e11,e12,e13

 a2 -> e21,e22,e23,e24,e25

 a3 -> e31,e32

 a4 -> e41,e42,e43,e44

 ...

 an -> en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6
```

I want to get all possible permutations with n elements in it from each array above.

For exm.

```
 e11,e21,e31,e41.........,en1

 e13,e25,e32,e41.........,en6
```

and so on...

Suggest me an efficient method and if possible code snippet in Java or C.

Comment: I would recursively loop through every combination.  This is simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following pseudo code:

Function to get next permutation:

```
function NextPermutation(int[] current)
{
    current[0] = current[0] + 1;
    int pointer = 0;
    while(pointer <= n && current[pointer] == limit[pointer])
    {
        current[pointer] = 0;
        pointer = pointer + 1;
        current[pointer] = current[pointer] + 1;
    }
}
```

Pre population code:

```
    int[] limit = new int[n + 2];
    int[] current = new int[n + 2];
    limit[1] = a1.length;
    ...
    limit[n] = an.length;

    while(current[n+1] == 0)
    {
        Print(current);
        NextPermutation(current);
    }
```

`current` array  containt indexes into arrays `a1, a2, ... , an`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in all array combinations For loop will be great here
Here is a solution(should be modified for syntaxes though to get it working)

```
int i = 0
int j=0
int k =0

while(i<arraylength(a1))
{
while (j < arraylength(a2))
{
//and so  till an
print a1[i],a2[j];
j++;
}
i++;
}
```